# SQL - Compare 2 Count values to update a Completion field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Example Scenario:

- an Order has 5 items
- each item has an individual bit column which determines whether or not they have been Received. (**ItemReceived**) *PartsTable*
- when all 5 items have been received , I want to update a (**OrderComplete**)field within the *OrdersTable*

I know the below code doesn't work but this is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
UPDATE OrdersTable SET OrderComplete = 1  
FROM PartsTable 
WHERE
     OrdersTable.OrderID = (SELECT TOP 1 OrderID FROM OrdersTable ORDER BY changedate DESC) 
AND 
    COUNT(PartsTable.ItemReceived) = COUNT(PartsTable.EquipmentID)
```

so when each individual part has been set as received (**ItemReceived**), then I want the `COUNT` function to compare this column to the **EquipmentID**

Example 1

- 4 Parts have been Received (**ItemsReceived** = **4**)
- 1 Part hasn't been Received
- COUNT(PartsTable.ItemReceived) **4** = COUNT(PartsTable.EquipmentID) **5**

In this scenario 4 doesn't equal 5 so nothing happens

Example 2

- 5 Parts have been Received (**ItemsReceived** = **5**)
- 0 Parts have not been Received
- COUNT(PartsTable.ItemReceived) **5** = COUNT(PartsTable.EquipmentID) **5**

In this scenario 5 equal's 5 so **OrderComplete** should equal **TRUE**

Thanks for any help with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` instead of using `COUNT`.

This would `UPDATE` all `Orders` to complete when there are no parts waiting to be received. If there are one or more parts still waiting to be received then the Order would not be updated to complete.

The join in the `NOT EXISTS` is likely incorrect as I am not sure how `OrdersTable` links to `PartsTable` but it should set you off in the right direction.

```
UPDATE
    OrdersTable

SET
    OrderComplete = 'TRUE'

FROM
    OrdersTable

WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    PartsTable
        WHERE   ItemReceived = 'FALSE'
                AND OrdersTable.Id = PartsTable.Id
    )
```